# sys.argv is splitting path if path is too long, how to make it not do that?

Tags: python, windows, filepath, sys

Python 3.9, Windows 10

So, I have a python script that accepts files drag-dropped onto it, what it does to the files should not be relevant.
Everything works fine except in the unusual cases where the file's path ends up longer than <s>the old 260(?) path limit or thereabouts</s> 257 characters (as counted in SublimeText). And yes I do have 'long paths' enabled in windows ('LongPathsEnabled'=1 in registry).

So to illustrate (actual paths is of course much longer)
File that gets drag-dropped is at `'x:\folder\folder 2\filename.file'`, sys.argv is correctly two arguments, `['pythonfile.py', 'x:\folder\folder 2\filename.file']`

If it is instead at `'x:\folder\folder 2\folder 3\filename.file'` (in real world going beyond the evident path limit) then sys.argv instead become 4 arguments, split at the blank spaces, as such: `['pythonfile.py', 'x:\folder\folder', '2\folder', '3\filename.file']`

So the script fails as sys.argv[1] isn't a file, only the first part of the path to it

So, what do? The only relevant piece of info I found was to let the python's installer remove the path limit, which I already did let it. Otherwise couldn't find a single mention of anything even resembling this problem nor how to potentially work around it.

As a backup solution I could potentially piece the path back together again when this happens, but it needs to be able to handle multiple files and I'm not sure of a sane way to check if it's a plethora of args because this happened or it's actually multiple files. Would be a pain for something that shouldn't happen to begin with...

Code for testing is `import sys, os;  print(sys.argv); os.system("pause")`
It's just a plain python file, files dragged on top of it, nothing else in-between, before or after. If the path to the files, including the filename+extension, is longer than 257 characters then what would normally be a single argument becomes multiple as it gets split up using up the spaces as delimiter.

No other imports, no external anything, just basic Python behavior on windows. Which just makes it all the more frustrating that it's impossible to find ANYTHING about it that could help.

Comment: I'm afraid it's going to be difficult to help you without more information, and particularly without any code.  You say files can be dropped on to it: presumably you are using a GUI framework such as PyQt/PySide, wxPython, tkinter, etc.?  Would it be possible to put together a minimal app that allows you to drag files onto it and just `print`s out the names of the files dropped?  If so, could you edit the question to include the code of this app?

Comment: It's only a python file, files dragged straight on top of it, sys.argv is a list of paths to the python file itself plus all files dropped onto it. The code to test this is literarily `import sys; print(sys.argv)`, that's all. Edited post nonetheless.

Comment: How do you make the script accept files drag-dropped onto it? I have created a simple script `droppable.py` in my Downloads folder, but Windows doesn't accept that I drag a file onto it.

Comment: In your example, the spaces in `/folder 2/` and `/folder 3/` are lost after the split.  Is this accurate, or did you mistype?  If it's accurate, that will make it _much_ harder to piece together the args...

Comment: The fault has to be in whatever piece of code translates the dropped files into command line args.  Do you know what code that is specifically?

Comment: @md2perpe Just base functionality of installing python, I did not do anything other than install it and restart and then it just worked for me.

Comment: @JohnGordon The spaces do disappear. 
Its just base Python functionality, you'd have to look at its source code for that if anything, or maybe if Python plugs into something in the operating system, but I have no clue about that.

Comment: I'm skeptical that the file dropping functionality is coming from stock Python.  What package, specifically, did you install?  Are you using an IDE or shell, i.e. something like VS Code or Pycharm?

Comment: I went to Microsoft Store and installed Python 3.10. I haven't restarted the computer but I restarted Explorer. I chose to always open .py files with Python 3.10. Drag-and-drop still not works

Comment: I don't know what to tell you mate, I downloaded the Python 3.9 windows installer whatever months or years ago from python.org and just installed it with that, I can't remember if I did anything relevant other than that. Try adding a shortcut to the python file in the window's SendTo folder and send files through that (right-click -> "send to" -> [python file name]), does exactly the same without literal drag-dropping.

Comment: I downloaded the installer from python.org and now drag-and-dropping works. But the path wasn't split on spaces.

Comment: I tried a deeper path. Still no problem.

Comment: Is the path ~240-260 or so characters long or longer? Anything shorter than about that works, as per the OP, it's the unusually long ones that don't. and just suddenly get split up. Doesn't matter how many folders or what characters are in the path, only the length seem to have an effect.